# Why do people say "Cut and paste" instead of "Copy and paste"?

Tags: differences, phrase-usage

I often see "cut and paste" used over "copy and paste" in the context of computers and word processing. I also see "cut and paste" and `CTRL-C`+`CTRL-V` used interchangeably when `CTRL-X` is the actual shortcut defined as "cutting" (on Windows).

When cutting and then pasting, the original copy is usually removed and duplicated at a new location - similar to moving the item. However, this usually doesn't work on websites with static text - `CTRL-X`+`CTRL-V` has no effect and only `CTRL-C`+`CTRL-V`performs the intended action of duplicating it elsewhere.

With this obvious difference between "cutting" and "copying", why do people still refer to it as "cutting and pasting" over "copying and pasting"?

Comment: It's because of the analogy to using scissors to cut out some text to paste it into a new place.  Like before there were computers, if you can imagine such a time.  If you move text printed on paper somewhere else, it goes missing from its original location.

Answer (score 2):

"Cut and paste" was used even before computers.  So (naturally) it was kept by early computer users.  And later computer users followed them.

The Oxford English Dictionary has a "cut and paste" example from 1772.

Answer (score 2):

Surely *cut and paste* has always preceded *copy and paste* for the simple fact that *cut and paste* would have been the more common pre-electronic editing activity.

[image: Cut and paste has always preceded copy and paste]

It is true that both *copy and paste* and *cut and paste* can be found in documents dating to at least the 18th century. In the former, the writer or editor writes copy and pastes it in a new location. In the latter, the original copy is cut from the manuscript and pasted elsewhere. But to insert, one could also write in an update by hand, so when pasting is involved, one might naturally assume that cutting had often been involved as well.

While the two activities were well-established by the time computerized word processing began to offer their digital metaphorical equivalents, *cut and paste* has maintained its preexisting popularity. The popularity of particular phrases isn't dependent on any inherent logic or descriptiveness.